# Terraform Import All Cloud Infrastructure Services to Statefile

Tags: terraform, alibaba-cloud

I 'm using many services in Alibaba Cloud like Container Service, VPC, RDS, DNS, OSS and many more.

Instead of importing 1 by 1 of Alibaba Cloud Product Services that used that would take a long time for that.

Is there any elegant and fast way to importing all of the cloud infrastructure to a statefile ?

Comment: Terraform doesn't directly support this but you might be interested in following https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/issues/170

Comment: You can use terraformer commands to import the stefiles and terraform manifest files from the existing resources in portal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a resource list and then run terraform but make sure you can have

Comment: Your answer seems to have stopped in mid sentence